# how to echo a class in php

Tags: php, html

i am using this php code:

```
<?php
class NumericHelper {
        public static function ToWordFa($number) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
    ?>
```

and i have `$creditPoints` which it is echoing some numbers:
i want to echo it as words and i do not know haw to do that.
how to do that?

Comment: you have undefined function error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example `ToWordFa` is defined as a static method in the class `NumericHelper`. To use it you must call it like this:

```
echo NumericHelper::ToWordFa($creditPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling ToWordFa() function outside of class Numeric Helper, you should use:-

```
$blah = new NumericHelper();
echo $blah->ToWordFa(2);
```